Are unique filtered indexes considered an antipattern for enforcing constraints?
I have a table, such as the following. Let's called it Fools.



FoolID
FoolValue
IsActiveFoolValue




1
Ultra Foolish
0


1
Super Foolish
1


2
Quite Foolish
1



A business rule is that for each FoolID, we can only have IsActiveFoolValue be 1 on one row. I want some sort of key or constraint to enforce this. However, to my knowledge, keys and constraints cannot do this. The only tool is a unique index like
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX OnlyOneActiveFoolValuePerFoolId
ON Fools(FoolID)
WHERE IsActiveFoolValue = 1 

is this considered an antipattern? Indexes aren't supposed to be constraints. They're supposed to be performance tools. Constraints should be enforced by keys, constraints, and maybe triggers. If it is considered an antipattern, what disadvantages does it bring and what alternatives exist?
I'm assuming SQL Server 2019, because some features of unique filtered indexes did not exist in very old versions and I want to keep my options open for any modern alternatives.

They are not quite considered an anti-pattern, but they are to some extent a denormalization.
Under very strict 6th Normal Form rules, you should really take out that bit column and instead make a separate table.
CREATE TABLE ActiveFool (
    FoolID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FoolValue VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY (FoolID, FoolValue),
    FOREIGN KEY (FoolID, FoolValue) REFERENCES Fools (FoolID, FoolValue)
);

But a filtered unique index essentially does the same thing, without a lot of the boiler-plate. It is a common way to enforce uniqueness over part of a table. You shouldn't feel this is problematic, it's a pretty standard way of dealing with this, and no worse than having nullable columns.
Furthermore, I don't agree with "Indexes aren't supposed to be constraints. They're supposed to be performance tools." You can't just add a unique constraint to table for performance, you need to know the data will conform. A unique index at the end of the day is a constraint, because it will throw an error on a duplicate.
And they are actually much better in many situations than a plain unique constraint, because they can have INCLUDE columns, so they can function as both at the same time.

On a side note, your particular example should probably have been implemented instead using Temporal Tables or some similar feature.

A more realistic use than a table of fools, would be a certain style of table with versioned rows, where the current row is marked. There can, of course, be only one current row, and there needs to be fast, indexed access to these.
I'd guess it's possible to abuse indexes somehow, but using a unique index to enforce uniqueness can hardly be an abuse.

The example is a bit odd.  You have FoolID which I would expect to be the primary key of the table.  Making it kind of a filtered primary key doesn't seem right.
Using a filtered index to ensure that something is unique within a subset of rows is fine.  Something along the lines of ensuring that the combination of Name and ParentID is unique but only where IsActive=1 might make sense.  That way you can soft-delete rows but allow an item with the same name to be re-created.
There are some things to watch out for.  Taking your example, the filtered index can't be used for these queries:
DECLARE @IsActive BIT=1
SELECT * FROM Fools WHERE FoolID = 1 AND IsActiveFoolValue=@IsActive
SELECT * FROM Fools WHERE FoolID = 1
SELECT * FROM Fools WHERE FoolID = 1 AND IsActiveFoolValue<>0

You need to be careful to always use IsActiveFoolValue=1 if you want to take advantage of the index on FoolID.  Or you might need to have an extra index on FoolID that isn't filtered that has extra overhead.
There might be alternative options you could consider but I don't think there is anything inherently wrong with using a unique filtered index.
